# FactoryGirl won't set an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am new to rails. Newer to FactoryGirl.

I have a model like this.

```
class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :scopes, Array

  :app_description
  :app_name
  :app_id
  :app_verson
  :dev_id
  :callback
  :manifest_ver
  :signed_jwt
  :scopes

  validates :app_name, presence: true
  validates :callback, presence: true
```

I have a factory like this.

```
  factory(:manifest) do
    callback "some callback"
    app_name "cool birds"
  end
```

The spec regarding above model is like this.

```
describe Manifest do
  describe "validation" do
    describe "of object from fractory" do
      it "must be ok" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:manifest).should be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I expected this test to pass. But it fails giving this output.

```
  1) Manifest validation of object from fractory must be ok
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:manifest).should be_valid
       expected #<Manifest id: nil, dev_id: nil, app_id: nil, app_description: nil, app_name: "cool birds", app_version: nil, manifest_ver: nil, callback: nil, signed_jwt: nil, scopes: [], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Callback can't be blank
```

It says Callback can't be blank.
It seems FactoryGirl ignores the value for attribute "callback".

when the spec changed to `FactoryGirl.build(:manifest, callback: "some callback").should be_valid` it works! The test passes.

FactoryGirl works for any other attribute in my model but "callback". Why? What wrong have I or this attribute named "callback" has done? What should I do to find out the problem.

Comment: My first guess, "callback" is probably reserved as a method name of sorts with FactoryGirl. Try to just proxy the attribute to see if it works, like   def cb=(_callback_)  self.callback = _callback_ end   to see if that works.

Comment: @CrazyVipa Yeah, your guess seems correct. That worked! Thank you very much!!!